# apt-get install -f fails

Tags: apt

Not sure what to do with this, apt-get dist-upgrade was the reason I want to run this, it says unresolved dependencies..

```
apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools libc6-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools libc6-dev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1292 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,955 kB of archives.
After this operation, 553 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.103ubuntu4.2.
 klibc-utils (2.0.3-0ubuntu1) breaks initramfs-tools (<< 0.103) and is installed.
  Version of initramfs-tools to be configured is 0.99ubuntu13.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error     from a previous failure.


    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu63); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on udev (>= 166-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 plymouth depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 mountall depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   dpkg: error processing mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initscripts:
 initscripts depends on mountall (>= 2.28); however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart:
 upstart depends on initscripts; however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package initscripts is not configured yet.
 upstart depends on mountall; however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing upstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of passwd:
 passwd depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing passwd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dmsetup:
 dmsetup depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
 dmsetup depends on udev (>> 141-2); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dmsetup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cron:
 cron depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cron (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus:
 dbus depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
 dbus depends on upstart (>= 0.6.3-6); however:
  Package upstart is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of accountsservice:
 accountsservice depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing accountsservice (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-x11:
 dbus-x11 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dbus-x11 (--configure):No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1:
 policykit-1 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing policykit-1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1-gnome:
 policykit-1-gnome depends on policykit-1; however:
  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing policykit-1-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnm-gtk0:
 libnm-gtk0 depends on policykit-1-gnome; however:
  Package policykit-1-gnome is not configured yet.
 libnm-gtk0 depends on dbus-x11; however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libnm-gtk0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-service:
 ubuntu-system-service depends on policykit-1; however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-system-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on libnm-gtk0; however:
  Package libnm-gtk0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on accountsservice; however:
  Package accountsservice is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on ubuntu-system-service (>= 0.1.10); however:
  Package ubuntu-system-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:
 libc6-dev depends on libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.
 libc6-dev depends on libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5); however:
  Version of libc-dev-bin on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.
dpkg: error processing libc6-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-label:
 plymouth-label depends on plymouth (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package plymouth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth-label (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (>= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (<< 2.97); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-mozilla:
 rhythmbox-mozilla depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-mozilla (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on udev (>= 149); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdevmapper1.02.1:
 libdevmapper1.02.1 depends on dmsetup (>= 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.3); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package dmsetup is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libdevmapper1.02.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 udev
 plymouth
 mountall
 initscripts
 upstart
 passwd
 dmsetup
 cron
 dbus
 accountsservice
 dbus-x11
 policykit-1
 policykit-1-gnome
 libnm-gtk0
 ubuntu-system-service
 gnome-control-center
 libc6-dev
 plymouth-label
 rhythmbox
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 rhythmbox-mozilla
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
 rhythmbox-plugins
 xserver-xorg-core
 libdevmapper1.02.1
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

my sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/     dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

# deb http://dl.hiphop-php.com/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe     multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted     universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please clean this post to make it a little more readable? There are some extra spaces making it harder to view the error reports. This seems to be dependency hell however. A tool like synaptic may help in the process of solving the dependency problems.

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: I get the same error mentioned above.  Running those commands together does little to solve the problem. E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: dist-upgrade alone gives same error.  I am going to be at the colo in a weeks time to reformat it if this persists, I am hoping its not neccesary

Comment: Yes, I have kind of the same exact problem, was going to ask a question myself...

Comment: Did you ever solve this?